# EF Core - How to define a one-to-one relationship based on two foreign fields with different names?

Tags: entity-framework, join, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, include

I am struggling to write the code to generate a foreign key relationship between a one-to-one relationship of `Bill` and `Pay`:

```
public class Bill
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public Guid WebSiteId { get; set; }
}

public class Pay
{
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public Guid WebSiteId { get; set; }
}
```

The naming was done poorly - `Identifier` is `Account`, but it's probably not worth the refactor at this moment (there's static raw SQL queries in the codebase referencing the names directly).

The way to join these two tables in SQL is like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Bills b
JOIN Pay p ON (b.Identifier = p.Account AND b.WebSiteId = p.WebSiteId)
```

And it will guarantee a one-to-one relationship between `Bill` and `Pay`.

How do I get EF core to understand this relationship?

I would like to use `.Include` for my joins:

```
context.Bills
    .Include(x => x.Pays)
```

Meaning my models would look something like this

```
public class Bill
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public Guid WebSiteId { get; set; }
    public virtual Pay Pay { get; set; }
}

public class Pay
{
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public Guid WebSiteId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bill Bill { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What are the primary keys?

Answer (score 1):

If you need both properties to uniquely identify a Pay, then I presume that you have a composite primary key on Pay entity.

```
builder.Entity<Pay>().HasKey(p => new { p.Account, p.WebSiteId });
```

In which case, you can configure the relationship using fluent API:

```
builder.Entity<Bill>()
    .HasOne<Pay>(b => b.Pay)
    .WithOne<Bill>(p => p.Bill)
    .HasForeignKey<Bill>(b => new { b.Identifier, b.WebSiteId });
```